# Show which field is empty using message box in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have simple entry field in tkinter app:

```
self.commentsEntry = Entry(self.frame)
self.qtyEntry = Entry(self.frame)
```

Next, I am trying to force the user to enter data if field is **empty** - and show a **messagebox** to show them which field needs to be filled out.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if self.commenttsEntry.get() == '':
    a = 'comments Entry Empty'
    pass

    if self.qtyEntry.get() == '':
        b = 'qty Entry Empty'
        messagebox.showerror("Error", a +'\n'+ b)
```

**Output**

***If both Entry fields are empty - output:***

```
comments Entry Empty
qty Entry Empty
```

***If commentsEntry is filled with text - output:***

*Nothing happends..* - no errors or anything.

How can I make it work? - if specific entry box is not filled - specify on the messagebox which one is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two conditions should be separate blocks; `if self.qtyEntry.get() == ''` shouldn't be inside `if self.commenttsEntry.get() == ''`.

Currently, your code is this:

```
if self.commenttsEntry.get() == '':
    a = 'comments Entry Empty'
    pass

    if self.qtyEntry.get() == '':
        b = 'qty Entry Empty'
        messagebox.showerror("Error", a +'\n'+ b)
```

If `self.commenttsEntry` is not empty, then the first `if` is not entered, and then the inner `if` is never reached.

Here's how you could do it:

```
errors = []
if self.commenttsEntry.get() == '':
    errors.append('comments Entry Empty')

if self.qtyEntry.get() == '':
    errors.append('qty Entry Empty')

if errors:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", '\n'.join(errors))
```

Comment: Is that what you observed when trying my suggestion?